# std::async vs std::promise

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, future

I have to wrap a getter function into a `std::future` object.
`std::function<String (String)>` -> `std::function<std::future<String> (String)>`

So simple question, what is the best / fastest way to do this?

Here are two options I came up with.

I have a function:

```
std::function<String (String)> getter;
```

Then wrap this using `std::promise`:

```
std::function<std::future<String> (String)> binding = [getter](String context) {
    std::promise<String> p;
    p.set_value(getter(contex));
    return p.get_future();
};
```

Or using `std::async`:

```
std::function<std::future<String> (String)> binding = [getter](String context) {
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred, getter, contex);
};
```

Comment: If you just want a future that's immediately read, go with the first approach (using an explicit promise).

Comment: It actually does not matter when it is ready or when the getter function is called. I just need it to fit into a list of futures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right answer is to write your own [`make_ready_future`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4313.html#futures.make_ready_future) (right out of `std::experimantal`).  `std::promise` is about the only way I know of to produce a ready future: `async` produces non-ready futures.

This takes a value, and produces a future of that value, with some fancy stuff involving reference wrappers (which you can optionally skip).

A proposal to add it in C++1z exists, so by basing your own version off its interface, you can semi future-proof your code.  Plus, as an audited design, it will suck less than your own.

Once you have it written:

```
template<class F>
auto futuristic_wrapper( F&& f ) {
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args){
    return make_ready_future( f( decltype(args)(args)... ) );
  };
}
```

in C++11 you'd have to write a class to replace the lambda:

```
template<class F>
struct futurize {
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  operator()(Args&&...args)const->
  delctype(make_ready_future(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
  { return make_ready_future(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }
};
template<class F>
auto futuristic_wrapper( F&& f )->
futurize< typename std::decay_t<F>::type >
{
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

which is annoying, but mostly a mechanical transformation.

This doesn't actually produce a `std::function< future<R>(Args...) >`, but it will return something convertible to that.  No need to type erase if we don't need to after all.

You can put "your own version of to-be-standardized stuff" you steal from `std::experimantal` in a namespace like `notstd`.  Always use it with `notstd::` (never `using namespace notstd;`, and not `using notstd::make_ready_future;` as that risk behavior changes when the type is added to `std`) to be clear to later users that this is NOT the standard version of these objects.

Comment: If I understand you right the benefit of make_ready_future over promise would be that the return value can be moved instead of being copied?

Comment: @waeco mainly that it expresses what you wsnt, exactly, and will probably be stsndardized.   So it will be easy to understand, and shortly may be improvable to a more efficient version.